# amazon ses attachments not visible for @yahoo receiver, but working for @gmail

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I'm trying to call Amazon Ses in python to send an email with attachments. If the receiver is a @gmail account, it works fine. However, if the receiver is @yahoo or some other email services, attachments do not get sent. What am I doing wrong?

```
def build_msg_html(cls, sender, receiver, subject, txt, html, attachment):
    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg['From'] = sender
    msg['To'] = receiver
    msg.attach(MIMEText(txt, 'plain', 'utf-8'))
    if html is not None:
        msg.attach(MIMEText(html, 'html', 'utf-8'))
    if attachment is not None:
        msg.attach(MIMEApplication(
            attachment.file.read(),
            Content_Disposition='attachment; filename="%s"' % attachment.filename,
            Name=attachment.filename
        ))
    return msg
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by following the answer from this question [Java Mail attachment not shown in outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27405511) : 
I replaced `MIMEMultipart('alternative')` with `MIMEMultipart()`